# Can't disable airplane mode on Lumia 620

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-620

I can't disable airplane mode on my Lumia 620. When I turn it off, in less than one second, it turns back on. What should I do?

Comment: Have you rebooted your phone?

Comment: Make sure the sim is properly inserted, and the mobile network has enough signals at the location you are at. You can also try with a different sim just to check

Comment: I have no SIM in my old 521 and it works just fine out of airplane mode via my household WiFi.

Answer (score 3):

Something is very wrong with your phone. The the following (stop when your phone works):

1. Reboot your phone
2. Reset your phone from the settings app
3. Use the Nokia Recovery Tool (or wherever its name is) and reset your phones software.

Comment: `Something is very wrong with your phone.` You don't say! :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to resolve this airplane mode issue:

1. Download the [Windows Device Recovery Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq)
2. Once installed, Open the tool
3. When it notifies, connect your phone
4. It checks for the latest update for your phone.
5. Click install (or reinstall if there is no update). The update gets downloaded into your PC then it will be installed

   The update will be around 1.5 Gb, you can disconnect your phone once the download starts. You need to reconnect it once the download is completed.
6. Then click install.

A big thing here is that the download size pretty large and the max speed would be around 200 kb (approx), even though you use high-speed internet connection.

One more thing: don't panic, your phone may restart few times during the installation process. Most probably it may take 20-25 mins for installation.

Comment: I found this was also the solution for the same issue with a Lumia 520.

A seemingly important note: it also said I had no SIM (it was properly inserted, had been working fine for years before, and my reseller provided a fresh SIM, still ignored) and it reported an IMEI of 864833591470879, which is nothing like my IMEI on the back of the phone (the one reported when it's working, of course). Googling that IMEI finds a couple of other hits suggesting it's trying to tell us something.

Comment: Issues with the Windows Device Recovery Tool: I received "operation completed with failure" after it attempted to update my Windows Phone (which it recognised, but seemed to not successfully put into flash mode). Googling for that issue suggests I need to use a "proper" Nokia USB cable, but mine did come with the phone. I got it to work by running the tool as admin, switching to my other USB3 port and leaving the phone displaying the drag-down page that includes current notifications and All Settings. I don't know which one of those was key.

Comment: One more "comment" removed from my edit: Now that it's provided by Microsoft, I noticed no issues downloading the 1.5 GB firmware update.